# iPhone Game, one phone faster than the other

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

This is very strange problem. Im creating an iPhone game and it runs on iPhone 4s.In The phone i used to test this it worked very well. However when i run it on an entirely different iPhone 4s, it runs at almost twice the speed. Would anyone know why this is?

Comment: What kind of phone is the second one? Also an iPhone 4s or an older model?

Comment: my game runs at 60 frames per second. and yes its an iphone 4s

Answer (score 2):

If it runs fine on one device, how is it a problem if it runs at twice the speed on another one? If your animations are be time based, there is no problem.
To the question itself: Maybe yours is the debug build, and the other device has the release from app store?

Comment: Also my animations are time based. They run at 60 fps. I used phonegap and jawsjs to make the game

Comment: I don't understand the question then, what do you mean by twice the speed?

Comment: Well i have a road and sprites.. All of these animate a lot faster than the other phone. For instance i have sprites/obstacles coming from the top. In the test phone and a lot of other phones it works fine. In one phone it travels at twice the speed